# What are the available meta information to get into a file using PHP?

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I am working for a PHP project that retrieves file **meta information**.
All I know are filename, file size, date modified.

Anybody knows the other meta information that can I get into a file using PHP?
If there are, would you write down the PHP code?

Comment: Are you after specific information? I mean if you're looking for what you can find out about a file, check http://www.php.net

Comment: You should probably specify exactly which information do you need to extract if you want concrete answers.

Comment: What kind of file, and on what file system? If you're looking for something universal, you pretty much listed them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for meta tags info, use `get_meta_tags()` to retrieve all meta information.

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```

**NEW EDIT** --

For File Info, you can use `fstat()` method --

> fstat — Gets information about a file using an open file pointer

```
<?php
// open a file
$fp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");

// gather statistics
$fstat = fstat($fp);

// close the file
fclose($fp);

// print only the associative part
print_r(array_slice($fstat, 13));
?>
```

`OUTPUT` -

```
Array
(
    [dev] => 771
    [ino] => 488704
    [mode] => 33188
    [nlink] => 1
    [uid] => 0
    [gid] => 0
    [rdev] => 0
    [size] => 1114
    [atime] => 1061067181
    [mtime] => 1056136526
    [ctime] => 1056136526
    [blksize] => 4096
    [blocks] => 8
)
```

Comment: @napstyrmaceda cheers :) and don't forget to accept if answer satisfies u ;)

Comment: @swapnesh - I'm sorry, I just understood your answer and your answer is not what I mean. not HTML meta-tags but meta-data in a file such as text files. thanks bfavaretto.